# Parsing Logs Using Google Guava

Tags: java, parsing, logging, guava

I am looking at way of parsing log file having log -- (Using Google Guava) in below format:

```
Sep 19 2006 13:23:40 MyDevice [latency][info] xmlfirewall (loopback-fw): tid(2809): Latency: 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 **999** 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 [http://<IP address>:9999/foo/test.xml]
```

I am reading log file using Google Guava

```
List < String > lines = Files.readLines(new File("C://my.log"), Charsets.UTF_8);
```

What I want to do is based on the user input (Start Time, End Time, IPAddress), I want to pickup only those line where we have IPAddess between start/end time and then produce an output like this

**Time,DeviceName,LatencyValue** -- In the above case the output will be

**05:13:40,MyDevice,999**

How Should I go about it.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [CharStreams.readLines](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html#readLines%28com.google.common.io.InputSupplier,%20com.google.common.io.LineProcessor%29) method and the [LineProcessor](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/LineProcessor.html) interface -- I've used that to do streaming parses of large files with good results.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Guava will help you there, and I personally wouldn't read the file to a list of lines, either.

Instead, I'd use a regular expression and run it over the entire text, like so:

```
// define pattern as constant
private static final Pattern PATTERN =
Pattern.compile("^.*(?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}.*$",Pattern.MULTILINE);

//now use the pattern in your code (inside a method):
List<String> matchingLines = Lists.newArrayList();
Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(logFileContentsAsString);
while(matcher.find()){
    String line = matcher.group();
    if(performSomeAdditionalTests(line, userData))
        matchingLines.add(line);
}
```

Comment: I am not good in Pattern/Regex Can you please share the complete code.

Comment: a) this is not PleaseWriteMyCodeForFree.com b) the other answer is better than mine, anyway